# Formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{10}{10+k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a normal problem solving I run into a sum:

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{10}{10+k}$

Let $n=20$ or something like that (not huge).  Browsing [a list of sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series) and [another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation), I'm not finding a formula for this one.

I'm wondering is it possible to find a formula for this type of sum, or if this type of sum has to be computed by a computer summing it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5035/1-1-2-1-3-1-n

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can express it using the [Harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) as $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{10}{10+k}=10(H_{10+n}-H_{10})\approx 10(\ln(10+n)-\ln(10))$  But if you want it exactly you need to add it up.

Comment: I evaluated $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{10}{10+k}=10\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{10+k}=10\sum_{k=11}^{10+n}\frac{1}{k}=10\left( H_{10+n}-H_{10}\right) 
$$

Comment: @Americo:  You are right.  I didn't read carefully.  Fixed