# Proving the existence of a limit

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove the existence of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}({\sum_{k=1}^{n}{1/k}-\log(n+1)})$, I have used the Integral Test Theorem applied to $f(x)=1/x(x+1)$ but I got nowhere unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n} \approx \ln(n) + \gamma$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804764/why-is-1-frac12-frac13-frac1n-approx-lnn-gamm)

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant