# Harmonic progression sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/algebra/arithmetic-geometric-and-harmonic-progressions

Please go to this link and see how they tell you to find the sum of harmonic prgression. However I am sure it is wrong as

$\frac{1}{a^{-1}+b^{-1}}\neq a+b $

I would like too understand and see the correct formula. Links will do.

P.S I am a ninth grader so don't go too high level math.

Comment: 1. I haven't found formula for harmonic sequence sum in the given link.
2. There is no good closed form expression. Even the basic harmonic sequence $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ as $n=1,2,3,\dots$ has no closed form for its sum (There are some approximations). You might want to read https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-general-formula-for-sum-of-n-terms-of-a-harmonic-progression

Comment: @galc127 scroll down the link page and they show how to find the sum. Their do not give formula.

Comment: I did, they don't show how to find the sum, only how to find each element of the sequence. They do not give formula, because as I have written and zz2Os answered - there is no such formula.

Comment: @galc127 It is clearly written there that the sum of HP will be the reciprocal of the sum of the respective AP. Isn't it wrong?

Comment: It is not written. What's written is that the term of HP will be the reciprocal of the term of AP. I tried to read the part of HP some times as I didn't want to miss anything. I do think you should read again and understand the difference between single term and sum.

Comment: @galc127. Yeah I should get my eyes checked .Got it and thanks for time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not know of a closed form for the partial sum of the harmonic sequence or any variation.

That is, there is no closed form for $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}$

Note that this is a partial sum. We can prove that the infinite sum of the reciprocals of the whole numbers diverges to infinity.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) you can find some information on so called "harmonic numbers." If you have any questions on what you read, feel free to comment. You may also want to see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5035/is-there-any-formula-for-the-series-1-frac12-frac13-cdots-frac-1-n?lq=1), but it uses some concepts from an introductory calculus class.