# Closed form of $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{i}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to figure out the closed form formula for the following:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{i}
$$

I think the denominator will have $N!$ in it but otherwise I cannot figure it out. Can someone help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5035/321264, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/451558/321264 ?

Comment: In short: there is no more convenient closed form. You can approximate it very accurately when $N$ grows very large, but that's pretty much all.

Comment: $\Psi(N+1) + \gamma$, where $\Psi$ is the ["digamma" function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).  That's about as closed as it's going to get.

Answer (score 3):

For a 'closed' form, look to this identity (but, there is no closed, closed form):

$$\text{S}=\sum_{\text{n}=a}^{\text{m}}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{\text{m}-1}+\frac{1}{\text{m}}=\psi^{(0)}(\text{m}+1)-\psi^{(0)}(\text{a})$$

Where $\psi^{(n)}(x)$ is the nth derivative of the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html).

---

When $a=1$:

$$\sum_{\text{n}=1}^{\text{m}}\frac{1}{n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{\text{m}-1}+\frac{1}{\text{m}}=\psi^{(0)}(\text{m}+1)-\psi^{(0)}(1)=\gamma+\psi^{(0)}(\text{m}+1)=\text{H}_{\text{m}}$$

Where $\text{H}_{\text{x}}$ is the xth [harmonic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html).