# How to find sum of finite HP

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was solving a question in which I required to calculate $$\sum_{a=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a}$$

I asked to my teacher he told me that there is no formula to calculate it

So I want to know how to find $\sum_{a=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a}$

Comment: What is the expression or quantity that is being summed?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/sum-of-harmonic-progression   There isn't a great closed form solution as such I guess.

Comment: To quote your teacher, "there is no formula [closed-form] to calculate it." What do you expect?

Comment: Just add up the terms, that's how. :p

Comment: i wanna sum for n=1000 or more than what

Comment: Consider reading the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get close, you can approximate the sum by $\int_1^n \frac{1}{x} \; dx = \ln n.$  The error will be really close to the Euler constant $\gamma = .5772156649,$ so you can add that in too.  E.g.,

$$\sum_{a=1}^{1000} \frac{1}{a} = 7.485470861.$$

and $\ln 1000 + \gamma = 7.484970943.$

There are refinements to the approximation, but we got 3 decimal places with just this.