# How to solve harmonic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

This question was actually derived from a time complexity recurrence relation question. Please also explain how is this a harmonic series.?$$\frac 1{\log (n)- i}$$

Comment: Let $N = \log(n)$ (we assume it's an integer here; it's fine for complexity computations). You are summing all numbers from $1/1$ to $1/(N-1)$, but in the opposite order: $\frac{1}{N-1} + \frac{1}{N-2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2 } +\frac{1}{1}$. Try to do a substitution $j = \log(n) - i$ and compute the limits on $j$ from the limits on $i$.

Comment: please can you explain how can solve this through arithmetic progression

Comment: For "time complexity" you only need to know how fast it grows asymptotically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence

Comment: how ? explain this plz

Answer (score 0):

Is $n$ supposed to be $k$? Otherwise, $\log (n)$ can be replaced by some constant $a$. If $a=k$ this is a partial sum of the harmonic series. For any $a$ this is a partial sum of the reciprocals of an arithmetic progression, i.e. of a [harmonic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_progression_(mathematics)). There is no closed form formula for partial sums of harmonic progressions (or even of harmonic series), but there are very good asymptotic approximations, see [Is there a partial sum formula for the Harmonic Series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496116/is-there-a-partial-sum-formula-for-the-harmonic-series) and [sum of harmonic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/sum-of-harmonic-progression)

Comment: i need a to find a way of solving  this harmonic progression

Comment: @S.Ohanzee What do you mean by solving?

Comment: by solve means my teacher informed me that harmonic progression cannot be solved until and unless you converge it into arithmetic function

Comment: @S.Ohanzee To "solve" a progression usually means finding a closed formula for its general term,  but you already have that. In the current version of OP there is no mention of the sum, so I do not know what the question is. Does "converge" mean that you want an asymptotic formula for the sum?